# Creating Hyperlinks When Writing A Comment?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, formatting

So last week I finally figured out how to create hyperlinks to a website when writing an answer and obviously it looks much more neat, tidy and professional than just providing the raw url.

How do I therefore create a hyperlink when writing a comment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy:

```
[link text](http://www.example.com/)
```

When writing a comment, you can also click the "help" link on the right of the comment box and receive further tips on writing and formatting with [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (the markup language used to format all posts on SE sites).

See more formatting tips on the [full editing guide for SE sites](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: And note that this style also works in questions and answers.